# MongoDB Highest rated books, to display title

Tags: arrays, mongodb, nosql, mongodb-query, nosql-aggregation

```
db.Books.aggregate( 
    {$unwind:'$rating'}, //unwinds rating array
    {$group:{_id:"$ISBN",avgR:{$avg:'$rating.book_rating'}}},
    {$sort : { avgR: -1 } }
).limit(5);
```

This query returns top 5 highest rated books

Collection is like:

```
{
    ISBN,
    Title,
    Rating:[ 
    {
        user,
        book_rating
    }
    ]
}
```

I have this query, within this i want to output Title of book.
How do I project it out? 
`{$project: {_id:0,"title":""}} // Wrong apparently`

Comment: Why don't you group by `Title` instead of `ISBN`? In that case you don't need to project anything.

Comment: hi thanks for suggestion but in this case I need both.

Comment: Then group by both: `{$group:{_id: {isbn: "$ISBN", title: "$Title"}`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quoted by @stackoverflow.com/users/1913537/ori-dar

Then group by both: {$group:{_id: {isbn: "$ISBN", title: "$Title"}.